# Swift add UIImage above custom tableView refresh control

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uirefreshcontrol

I would like to add a UIImage just above a custom table view refresh control.

Im not sure If I should add the image to the **tableView.backgroundView** or somehow include it in the custom refresh control.

**Code:**

```
var nvActivityIndicator : NVActivityIndicatorView?

func configActivityLoader()  {
        
        // Create refresh control and add as subview in your table view.
        tableView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        //refreshControl.backgroundColor = .red
        tableView.refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshWithPull), for: .valueChanged)
        tableView.refreshControl!.tintColor = .clear
        
        // Create NVActivityIndicator view and add as subview inside refresh control
        nvActivityIndicator = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: tableView.refreshControl!.bounds, type: NVActivityIndicatorType.ballPulse, color: activityLoaderColor.withAlphaComponent(0.45), padding: 50)
        nvActivityIndicator?.backgroundColor = tableView.refreshControl!.backgroundColor
        nvActivityIndicator?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        
        //        let refreshImage = UIImageView()
        //        refreshImage.image = UIImage(named: "satoshi")
        //tableView.refreshControl!.addSubview(refreshImage)
        
        tableView.refreshControl!.addSubview(nvActivityIndicator!)
        
        // Add constraint to auto resize nvActivityIndicator as per refresh control view.
        let nvActivityIndicator_top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: nvActivityIndicator!, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: tableView.refreshControl, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let nvActivityIndicator_bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: nvActivityIndicator!, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: tableView.refreshControl, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let nvActivityIndicator_leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: nvActivityIndicator!, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: tableView.refreshControl, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let nvActivityIndicator_trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: nvActivityIndicator!, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: tableView.refreshControl, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        
        // Add constrains
        tableView.refreshControl!.addConstraint(nvActivityIndicator_top)
        tableView.refreshControl!.addConstraint(nvActivityIndicator_bottom)
        tableView.refreshControl!.addConstraint(nvActivityIndicator_leading)
        tableView.refreshControl!.addConstraint(nvActivityIndicator_trailing)
        
        
    }
```

Library Used: [NVActivityIndicatorView](https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView)

**GOAL:**

> ```
>                           [image]
>
>                 Activity loader under image
> ```

Comment: You are *not sure* what you should do? What did your code do? Did it do what you want?